# Presenting a semi-transparent UITableView from a UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm working on an app that will rely on one main view controller with a row of buttons at the bottom to display other views with information. From one of these buttons I want to present a tableview that presents a list of song titles. This app plays sound files, and I want the user to be able to tap a button, then select a song to be the default song to play. I want to present this tableview with a uiview animation, and I want it to be semi-transparent and only fill a portion of the screen. I've tried creating a UITableViewController and then presenting it from the main view controller like so:

```
UITableViewController *tableView = [[UITableViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:tableView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This presents a view controller that fills the entire screen though, which is not what I want. And changing the view controller's frame at instantiation time doesn't seem to have an effect. I can just animate a UITableView into the main view controller's view, but then I'm not so sure who is supposed to be the delegate and data source. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of animation do you want? It sounds like you should be animating in a view (the table) not a new controller.

Comment: I'm just animating the view using [UIView animateWithDuration:]. The animation works fine if I just use a view, but I'm not sure if I can prevent a UITableView this way since it needs a Data source and delegate. Can I just set the Main view controller to be the delegate and data source when I animate the table view into the view?

Comment: Yes, sure you can. Any object that adopts the UITableViewDataSource protocol can be a table data source.

Comment: "prevent" should have been "present". And ok I'll give it a shot. I guess I was just confusing myself because I've presented a table view this way. I'll post code if I'm successful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While adding table view as a subview, u can set its frame size or bound, and display it with animation whatever you like. Yes, you can set delegate and datasource to self while adding .

I use: (in viewDidLoad)

```
 self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.opaque = NO;
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:.55];
```

Not sure if this is what you wanted, but it gives you the option to make everything clear. (obviously the alpha would change for your case, but that measures the opacity of the cells)